# timer.scheduleAtFixedRate does not stop when i call cancel

Tags: java, android, timertask

At onCreate, I run a task that repeats every minute. Here how I do it:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
    int delay = 30000;   // delay for 30 sec.
    int period = 600000;  // repeat every 60 sec.
    doThis = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {

                     Log.v("TImer","repeated");
                     wv.reload();

      }
    };

    myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doThis, delay, period);
```

All that code is in onCreate. So, when the app goes off from the screen, I can see in logcat that timer steel runs, and will not stop unless the app will be destroyed. So, in `onPause` of activity I call `myTimer.cancel();` but it didnt help. I still can see updates in logcat, even when the app is not on the screen. So, how to stop `timerTask`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your code put into my file, with the values delay and period tweaked so I don't have to wait so long. I run the app. I see the messages in LogCat. I press the home button on my Galaxy S3. Then the messages stop in LogCat.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Timer myTimer;
    TimerTask doThis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTimer = new Timer();
        int delay = 0;   // delay for 30 sec.
        int period = 1000;  // repeat every 60 sec.
        doThis = new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {

                         Log.v("TImer","repeated");

          }
        };

        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doThis, delay, period);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        myTimer.cancel();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange. Does Log.v show anything in your onPause method? If not, I think it might be spelled wrong, or maybe your P is not upper case or something else out of place -- so it is not actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that since the thread has already been sent out, it runs one last time. In the onLoad set a variable to true, then in the onPause  set it to false. Then in your timer task only run your code if the variable is true.

Write to the log outside of the new if statement though. If it is indeed running it just one last time, then that might be your solution. But if it is still running it over and over multiple times after the onPause then don't take my solution.

Comment: Your code works for me, except I took of wv.reload();  -- Not sure what you are doing in that method. Is it something that would cause the app to start again?

Comment: Also, can you put a Log.v on your onPause method to make sure it is actually getting fired?

Comment: wv.reload, i just reload a webview. strange that it works for you

Answer (score 0):

**The actual answer is**: The `onPause` method needs to be defined correctly.

**The whole story:**
The questioner defined the `onPause` method wrong. That was the reason for asking this question.

I'm writing this because I spent too much time reading question, answers, code and comments. The real answer was hidden in the last comment.